# Position of Non-finite verb forms

Tags: grammar, verb, word-order

As I see, when using a verb compound, the helping verb should always be placed in the second position of the sentence while the non-finite verb form (or the main/second verb) usually at the end, but sometimes at the beginning.

My question is could the second verb also be placed in positions other than at the beginning or the end of the sentence? (e.g the second last position? )

> Solche Anwohnerbiotope, Schmelztiegel unterschiedlichster Daseinsentwürfe, **werden** allerorten **ersetzt durch** Kettenprodukte.

In this example "ersetzt" goes neither at the end nor the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: The standard order would indeed be _werden allerorten durch Kettenprodukte ersetzt_, with _ersetzt_ in the final position; but parts of the sentence may be moved behind it. See the Basel question.

Comment: It's possible, as you can see from the suggested duplicate question or [this background information (in German)](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Nachfeld.html#Anchor-14210).

Comment: The explanation linked to by @Matthias is also available in English (like all Canoo.net content, just click on the Union Jack at the top of each page): http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Nachfeld.html?lang=en

Comment: @chirlu Thank you, I never noticed it. Heres the deep link to the section that applies to both this question and the duplicate: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Nachfeld.html?lang=en#Anchor-14210